# Custom TimeStamp property in EF code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, timestamp, disconnected-environment

I'm using EF 6.1 code first in my project. For following entity, I want to increment `Version` field value in database when **only**`Code` and `Name` values changed(I update my Entities in a disconnected scenario):

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Code {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public int Version {get; set;}
}
```

Using `[TimeStamp]` annotation cause the `[TimeStamp]` property changes when any property value of entity change.

Is there any way to do this work in EF?

Comment: You should do this in a database trigger to prevent concurrency issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the state of the property changed or not.[Here MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj592677.aspx)

You update code may look like this.

```
  public void Update(Product product) {
        if (context.Entry(product).Property(u => u.Code).IsModified && context.Entry(product).Property(u => u.Name).IsModified) {
            product.Version += 1;
        }
        context.Entry(product).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

Comment: I'm working in a disconnected environment, so I can't use `IsModified` property.